# Gallery of TextViews

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am trying to use a Gallery to make a set of scrolling TextViews that click into place. I have gone through the HelloGallery tutorial, but am stuck at extending BaseAdapter.

How could I extend BaseAdapter to make TextViews that go into the Gallery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. This is a basic implementation. You can extend this adapter with dynamic add view functionality, but this is somewhat outside the scope.

```
class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{
    private Context context;
    private Vector<TextView> views;

    public CustomAdapter(Context c, Vector<TextView> views)
    {
        this.context = c;
        this.views = views;
    }



    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            convertView = new TextView(context);
        }

        ((TextView)convertView).setText(views.get(position).getText());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return views.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TextView getItem(int position) 
    {
        return views.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ha! People still use `Vector`!

Comment: Exactly. So you'll pay the penalty for locking. Since the adapter will only be called on the UI/main thread, there is little value of locking *all* operations.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need to use a custom adapter. You could just use default `ArrayAdapter` like so, where the `my_item` layout contains a single (appropriately styled) `TextView`:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.my_item, items);
```